# How to convert GPS degree to decimal and vice-versa in jquery or javascript and PHP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gps

does someone know how to convert GPS degree to decimal values or vice versa?

I have to develop a way where users can insert an address and get the GPS values (both degree and/or decimal), but the main thing i need to know is how to convert the values, cause users can also insert GPS values (degree or decimal). Because i need to get the map from google maps this needs decimal.

I've tryed some codes but i get big numbers...like this one:

```
function ConvertDMSToDD(days, minutes, seconds, direction) {
    var dd = days + minutes/60 + seconds/(60*60);
    //alert(dd);
    if (direction == "S" || direction == "W") {
        dd = '-' + dd;
    } // Don't do anything for N or E
    return dd;
}
```

Any one?

Thank you.

Comment: Your function works perfect: http://jsfiddle.net/fuRED/2/

Comment: @Eugen Rieck the problem is that is you try this value `ConvertDMSToDD(41, 11, 1, "N")` it will return a big number, and google maps do not recognizes it!

Comment: Works for me again: http://jsfiddle.net/fuRED/3/ - maybe it is a browser issue? I tried Chrome and FF (current versions on Ubuntu Lucid)

Comment: I found this [link](http://transition.fcc.gov/mb/audio/bickel/DDDMMSS-decimal.html) which is good, but they don't have a function everything is inside the html code. I saw that they divide somewhere the number for 1000000....i'm trying to make a function of this to understand it...

Comment: The linky ou gave uses "form10.alat.value = Math.round(absdlat + (absmlat/60.) + (absslat/3600.) ) * latsign/1000000;" as a formula. The multiplication is just there to kill rounding problems.

Comment: Ok i found the problem i was passing values as stirngs which return a crazy number! `ConvertDMSToDD("41", "11", "1", "N")` problem salved! Thank you very much. (how do i end this discussion?)

Comment: You might want to harden your function by doing something like "if (typeof(seconds)!='number') seconds=parseInt(''+seconds); if (isNaN(seconds)) return -9999999;" ofcours for d,m and s. Additionally you might want to allow upper and lowercase : "W"=="w" ...

Comment: @EugenRieck one last thing how do i know from decimal values if it is E W S or N? I know that if value is < 1 is S or W, but how do i know? Thank you.

Comment: That depends on your input! If you put in a Lattitude ("N" or "S"), then you will get <0 for south, >0 for north and ==0 for the Aequator. If you put in a Longitude ("W","E") you will get <0 for West of Greenwich, >0 for East of Greenwich and ==0 for the zero meridian

Answer (score 9):

First thank you @Eugen Rieck for your help.
Here is my final code, hope it can help someone:

degree to decimal

```
function getDMS2DD(days, minutes, seconds, direction) {
    direction.toUpperCase();
    var dd = days + minutes/60 + seconds/(60*60);
    //alert(dd);
    if (direction == "S" || direction == "W") {
        dd = dd*-1;
    } // Don't do anything for N or E
    return dd;
}
```

decimal to degree based on this [link](http://transition.fcc.gov/mb/audio/bickel/DDDMMSS-decimal.html)

```
function getDD2DMS(dms, type){

    var sign = 1, Abs=0;
    var days, minutes, secounds, direction;

    if(dms < 0)  { sign = -1; }
    Abs = Math.abs( Math.round(dms * 1000000.));
    //Math.round is used to eliminate the small error caused by rounding in the computer:
    //e.g. 0.2 is not the same as 0.20000000000284
    //Error checks
    if(type == "lat" && Abs > (90 * 1000000)){
        //alert(" Degrees Latitude must be in the range of -90. to 90. ");
        return false;
    } else if(type == "lon" && Abs > (180 * 1000000)){
        //alert(" Degrees Longitude must be in the range of -180 to 180. ");
        return false;
    }

    days = Math.floor(Abs / 1000000);
    minutes = Math.floor(((Abs/1000000) - days) * 60);
    secounds = ( Math.floor((( ((Abs/1000000) - days) * 60) - minutes) * 100000) *60/100000 ).toFixed();
    days = days * sign;
    if(type == 'lat') direction = days<0 ? 'S' : 'N';
    if(type == 'lon') direction = days<0 ? 'W' : 'E';
    //else return value     
    return (days * sign) + 'º ' + minutes + "' " + secounds + "'' " + direction;
}
alert(getDD2DMS(-8.68388888888889, 'lon'));
```

`

Comment: I know this is an old post but thank you so much for posting your final code. I've been trying to do this for the past hour. I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

couldnt get the script above working, after some time came up with this;
just give the dms to the function

```
function ConvertDMSToDEG(dms) {   
    var dms_Array = dms.split(/[^\d\w\.]+/); 
    var degrees = dms_Array[0];
    var minutes = dms_Array[1];
    var seconds = dms_Array[2];
    var direction = dms_Array[3];

    var deg = (Number(degrees) + Number(minutes)/60 + Number(seconds)/3600).toFixed(6);

    if (direction == "S" || direction == "W") {
        deg = deg * -1;
    } // Don't do anything for N or E
    return deg;
}
```

and visa versa just give the degrees to the script, and true of false for lat (latitude)

```
function ConvertDEGToDMS(deg, lat) {
    var absolute = Math.abs(deg);

    var degrees = Math.floor(absolute);
    var minutesNotTruncated = (absolute - degrees) * 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(minutesNotTruncated);
    var seconds = ((minutesNotTruncated - minutes) * 60).toFixed(2);

    if (lat) {
        var direction = deg >= 0 ? "N" : "S";
    } else {
        var direction = deg >= 0 ? "E" : "W";
    }

    return degrees + "°" + minutes + "'" + seconds + "\"" + direction;
}
```

hope this helps people..